# Equivalence of definition of measurable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Just a quick question on the structure of the following proof. My book defines a function $f$ to be measurable on $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, if for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the set

$$f^{-1}([-\infty , a)) = \{x \in E: f(x) < a\}$$

is measurable.

Next it is claimed that we have an equivalent definition if we use the inverse image of closed intervals (they use an *iff* statement). The proof is obtained by seeing that in one direction we have

$$\{f \leq a\} = \bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty \{f < a + 1/k\} \tag{1}$$

and in the other direction

$$\{f  < a\} = \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty \{f \leq a - 1/k\} \tag{2}$$

Noting that for $(1)$ a countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable.

---

Okay, so I take the proof to mean that for $(1)$ we are proving the following: If $\{f < a\}$ is measurable, then $\{f \leq a\}$ is measurable. Then we show that because the right hand side is a measurable set for all $k$ **by definition**, and its countably infinite intersection is the left side.

For $(2)$ I believe that we are showing the same thing, essentially in reverse.

Really what I'm asking is: is the bolded reason above correct?

Comment: For (1) you assume that $\{f<x\}$ is measurable for every $x$. Therefore, the LHS of (1) is measurable as a  countable intersection of measurable sets...

Comment: YES.  Let $G$ be any family of Borel sets in $\Bbb R $such that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $S$ on $\Bbb R$ such that $S\supset G$ is the set $B$  of all Borel sets.  (i.e. $G$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra B).  Then $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}H$ is measurable for every $H\in  G$.... If $G^*$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $G$, and $G\subset B,$ then in order for $G^*=B$ it is sufficient that  $G^*$ includes every interval, or every closed  interval, or every open interval, or... (it goes on & on).

Comment: A more common  (equivalent ) def'n of a measurable function is that $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}U$ is a measurable set whenever $U$ is open.